# List not sorted after applying HeapSort implemented in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to implement heapSort in java but not getting the sorted list after executing. Can you suggest what i am doing wrong here? I created a method Heapsort to sort the heap which calls heap itself. Once the heap is called it gives me a heap tree containing the largest element at the top. I am assuming my interchange or further process is not working properly. What's wrong in here?

```
  public class HeapSort 
  {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    int a[]=new int[]{30,100,20,80,40,90,50,60};
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    heapSort(a);
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]+"\t");
    }
}
public static void heapSort(int a[])
{
    int i, temp;
    for(i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        heap(a);
        temp=a[0];
        a[0]=a[i];
        a[i]=temp;
    }
}
public static void heap(int a[])
{
    int i,j,k,temp;
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        j=i;
        k=(i-1)/2;
        while(k>=0&&a[j]>a[k])
        {
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[k];
            a[k]=temp;
            j=j/2;
            k=k/2;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the standard `Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(a))`? You'd only have to put Integer objects in your `a` array. I believe the default implementation is a modified version of [mergesort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

Comment: I am learning sorting and algorithms and wanted to understand how things work. Would really appreciate where i am doing it wrong. I am skeptical on the interchange part in the heapsort function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to debug your code.

Or you could do it old style, and insert print statements, so you can see a pattern in the intermediate results.

Adding print statements at beginning and end of `heap()` method:

```
public static void heap(int a[])
{
    System.out.println("heap in : " + Arrays.toString(a));
    // existing code
    System.out.println("heap out: " + Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

*Output*

```
heap in : [30, 100, 20, 80, 40, 90, 50, 60]
heap out: [100, 90, 80, 60, 40, 20, 50, 30]
heap in : [30, 90, 80, 60, 40, 20, 50, 100]
heap out: [100, 90, 80, 60, 40, 20, 50, 30]
heap in : [50, 90, 80, 60, 40, 20, 100, 30]
heap out: [90, 60, 100, 50, 40, 20, 80, 30]
heap in : [20, 60, 100, 50, 40, 90, 80, 30]
heap out: [100, 90, 80, 30, 40, 60, 50, 20]
heap in : [40, 90, 80, 30, 100, 60, 50, 20]
heap out: [90, 100, 80, 30, 40, 60, 50, 20]
heap in : [30, 100, 80, 90, 40, 60, 50, 20]
heap out: [100, 90, 80, 30, 40, 60, 50, 20]
heap in : [80, 90, 100, 30, 40, 60, 50, 20]
heap out: [100, 80, 90, 30, 40, 60, 50, 20]
heap in : [80, 100, 90, 30, 40, 60, 50, 20]
heap out: [100, 80, 90, 30, 40, 60, 50, 20]
```

Do you see the problem?

Heap Sort is supposed to push the largest value to the last position, then the second largest to the second last position, and so on...

But, `100` keeps moving. Why? Because you send the *entire* array in to `heap()` on *every* call.

Change from `heap(int a[])` to `heap(int a[], int len)`.
Replace `i<a.length` with `i<len` in `heap` method.
Change `heap(a);` to `heap(a, i + 1);` in `heapSort` method.

Problem fixed.